# How to avoid duplication of code in class?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have two classes that extend abstract class:

```
   class SubstitutionTeacher extends SubstitutionAbstract {
      abstract _save();
    }

    class SubstitutionFree extends SubstitutionAbstract {
      public _save() {
      }
    }

    class SubstitutionSubject extends SubstitutionAbstract {
      public _save() {
      }
    }
```

In method `save()` I realize own behaviour like this:

```
  /* Class SubstitutionFree
    public _save() {

        const substitutionAdd: ISubstitutionModelTeacher = {
          lesson: this.substitution.lessonNumber,
          confirmed: true,
          subsDate: this.substitution.date,
          newTeacher: this.substitution.teacher
        };

        return this.replaceService.addSubstitution(substitutionAdd);
      }

 /* Class SubstitutionSubject
    public _save() {

        const substitutionAdd: ISubstitutionModelTeacher = {
          lesson: this.substitution.lessonNumber,
          confirmed: true,
          newTeacher: this.substitution.teacher
        };

        return this.replaceService.addSubstitution(substitutionAdd);
      }
```

As you can see both method are almost similar. I want to avoid this duplication:

```
{ lesson: this.substitution.lessonNumber,
confirmed: true,
newTeacher: this.substitution.teacher
}
```

I can change `save()` to regular `save()` and pass there a common part but it losts meaning of abstraction.

Comment: just move it to some method, make that method to return this stuff and call that single method where you need it. I guess you could add this method to `SubstitutionAbstract`

Comment: Do you mean to do this method not abstract, can you share a sample?\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be invalid typescript, just because I am not that good in typescript :)

But your problem is not typescript specific, so maybe this will give you an idea of how such problems can be fixed.

Create a method in `SubstitutionAbstract` :

```
class SubstitutionAbstract {

    // this one should be called each time you need that object instead of duplicating
    // you can make it protected if there is such stuff in typescript
    public getMyStuff(param1, param2, param3, param4) {
        return { lesson: param1,
                 confirmed: param2,
                 newTeacher: param3,
                 subsDate: param4
               };
    }  
    // .....
}
```

In each your subclass just call it:

```
public _save() {
    const substitutionAdd: ISubstitutionModelTeacher = 
             getMyStuff(this.substitution.lessonNumber, true, 
                           this.substitution.date, this.substitution.teacher);

    return this.replaceService.addSubstitution(substitutionAdd);
}
```

If you don't need `subsDate` in some implementation then pass `null` for that one to `getMyStuff`, don't think it can be a problem. Typescript probably checks types etc., so you might need to play with that method to make work (e.g. it should return something of type `ISubstitutionModelTeacher` I guess).

And again - this is probably **not working code**, because typescript is not my area, but it describes the idea of how you could do.

And sure there could be other ways, this is just 1 example.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Can I do something as: return IMode:= {...para,eters}?

Comment: Or like this: `return {} as IModel;` ?

Comment: And this is a typescript-specific question that I cannot answer correctly, sorry ) Just try both maybe if you're not sure and check the behavior of your code in both cases. Maybe there is no difference.